# How to hide the information, just only show when button is clicked html, css. javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know how to hide the information for **terms**(button) and **enumeration**(Button). The information should only appear when a button is clicked or chosen. Hope for good answers. Thank you!! If you have suggestion to my html and css that will make that show and hide easily made.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
 width: 960px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
}html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-size: 11pt;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #363636;
}
a{text-decoration:none}

.wrapper{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
.header{
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.header img {
 width: 360px;
}

#nav {
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 1em;
 border-top-width: medium;
 border-top-style: groove;
 border-bottom-style: groove;
 border-bottom-width: medium;
}
#nav a{ letter-spacing: 1px;}
#nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 font-size: larger;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li a {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: relative;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#nav ul li a.active {
 text-decoration:underline;
 color: #EDF0BA;  
}
div.navigation li { list-style: none; }

div.navigation li:hover { background: #555;  }
div.navigation li:hover ul { display: block;  }
.how, .about{
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: left;
 color: black;
}
.sectiontitle{
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #767676;
}
.footer{
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
 border-style: groove hidden hidden;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
 padding-top: 1%;
 padding-bottom: 1%;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.addnotes {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 2%;
 font-color: black;
}
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.glyphicon-trash:before {
  content: "\e020";
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
      touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-sm,
 {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.btn-default{color:#333;background-color:#fff;border-color:#ccc}

.listnotes {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.listnotes li {
 background: url('noteicon.png') no-repeat;
 width: 220px;
 height: 135px;
 margin-left: 45%;
 padding-top: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.noteTitle { 
 float: left;
 left: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 color: black;
}
.buttons{ 
 margin-top: 100px;
 color: black;
}
.createcontent {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.definition {
 padding-top: 10%;
}

.enumeration {
 padding-top: 15%;
}

#titletextbox {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
 width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px){
.wrapper{
width: 320px;
}
#nav {
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 10px;
 border-top-width: thin;
 border-top-style: thin;
 border-bottom-style: thin;
 border-bottom-width: thin;
}
#logo{
margin-top: 5px;
 width: 50%;
}

.footer{
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
 border-style: groove hidden hidden;
 padding-bottom: 1%;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.listnotes li {
 background: url('noteicon.png') no-repeat;
 width: 100;
 height: 100;
 margin-left: 35%;
 padding-top: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.createcontent{
 font-size: 14px;
}
.listnotes{
 font-size: 14px;
}
a{text-decoration:none}
}


@font-face {
font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format(embedded-opentype),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format(woff2),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format(woff),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format(truetype),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format(svg);
}

.glyphicon {
position:relative;
top:1px;
display:inline-block;
font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
font-style:normal;
font-weight:400;
line-height:1;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
}


.glyphicon-plus:before {
content:"\2b";
}

.glyphicon-remove:before {
content:"\e014";
}

.glyphicon-trash:before {
content:"\e020";
}



.glyphicon-floppy-save:before {
content:"\e175";
}


.btn {
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:0;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:400;
line-height:1.42857143;
text-align:center;
white-space:nowrap;
vertical-align:middle;
-ms-touch-action:manipulation;
touch-action:manipulation;
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
background-image:none;
border:1px solid transparent;
border-radius:3px;
padding:6px 12px;
}

.btn.focus,.btn:focus,.btn:hover {
color:#333;
text-decoration:none;
}

.btn.active,.btn:active {
background-image:none;
outline:0;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.125);
box-shadow:inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}

.btn-default {
margin-top: 10px;
color:#333;
background-color:#fff;
border-color:#ccc;
}

.btn-default.active,.btn-default.focus,.btn-default:active,.btn-default:focus,.btn-default:hover,.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
color:#333;
background-color:#e6e6e6;
border-color:#adadad;
}

.btn-primary {
color:#fff;
margin-left: -50px;
background-color:#337ab7;
border-color:#2e6da4;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn-primary1 {
color:#fff;
margin-left: -10px;
background-color:#337ab7;
border-color:#2e6da4;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left:20px;
}
.form-control {

width:100%;
height:20px;
font-size:14px;
line-height:1.42857143;
color:#555;
background-color:#fff;
background-image:none;
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-radius:4px;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
-webkit-transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
-o-transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
padding:6px 12px;
}

.col-sm-2 {
width:20%;
float: left;
font-size: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.col-sm-10 {
width:80%;
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.DemoBS2{
margin-top: 110px;
margin-left: 40px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:0;
font-size:14px;
text-align:left;
vertical-align:middle;
-ms-touch-action:manipulation;
touch-action:manipulation;
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
background-image:none;
border:1px solid transparent;
border-radius:3px;
padding:6px 12px;
}
p{
    background:#444;
    color:#4ee255;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px 0px;
    border:2px solid #fa4b2a;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:4px 4px 4px #ccc;
   
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png">
      <title>Create notes</title>
      <link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/style3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="header" id="header">
            <div class="logo"> <img src = "logo.png" alt = "logo" name = "logo" id = "logo"> </div>
         </div>
         <div class="navigation" id="nav">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="notes.html" class='active'><span>Notes</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="exam.html"><span>Exams</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="noteTitle">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Title:</label> 
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
               <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="titleofnote" value="Note 1" placeholder="Click here to enter title.">
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="saveAndClose()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span> Save and close</a>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  
<div class="DemoBS2">
  <!-- Toogle Buttons -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" 
  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle-example">Terms</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" 
  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle-example">Enumerations</button>
    <div id="toggle-example" class="collapse in">
      <p>I don't know how to hide this. This should only show</b>
   when the button is clicked in terms(button)</b>Please help thanks.</p></div>
</div>
  
        
      </div>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/createscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(".btn1").click(function() {
  $("#toggle-example").fadeToggle();
})
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 body {
  width: 960px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#toggle-example {
  display: none
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #363636;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.header img {
  width: 360px;
}
#nav {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-top-width: medium;
  border-top-style: groove;
  border-bottom-style: groove;
  border-bottom-width: medium;
}
#nav a {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: larger;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#nav ul li a.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #EDF0BA;
}
div.navigation li {
  list-style: none;
}
div.navigation li:hover {
  background: #555;
}
div.navigation li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
.how,
.about {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}
.sectiontitle {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #767676;
}
.footer {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: groove hidden hidden;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.addnotes {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2%;
  font-color: black;
}
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.glyphicon-trash:before {
  content: "\e020";
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-sm,
{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.btn-default {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc
}
.listnotes {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.listnotes li {
  background: url('noteicon.png') no-repeat;
  width: 220px;
  height: 135px;
  margin-left: 45%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.noteTitle {
  float: left;
  left: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  color: black;
}
.buttons {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: black;
}
.createcontent {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.definition {
  padding-top: 10%;
}
.enumeration {
  padding-top: 15%;
}
#titletextbox {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 320px;
  }
  #nav {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-top-style: thin;
    border-bottom-style: thin;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
  }
  #logo {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .footer {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: groove hidden hidden;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .listnotes li {
    background: url('noteicon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 100;
    height: 100;
    margin-left: 35%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .createcontent {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .listnotes {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none
  }
}
@font-face {
  font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format(embedded-opentype),
  url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format(woff2),
  url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format(woff),
  url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format(truetype),
  url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format(svg);
}
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.glyphicon-plus:before {
  content: "\2b";
}
.glyphicon-remove:before {
  content: "\e014";
}
.glyphicon-trash:before {
  content: "\e020";
}
.glyphicon-floppy-save:before {
  content: "\e175";
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
.btn.focus,
.btn:focus,
.btn:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn.active,
.btn:active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}
.btn-default {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-default.active,
.btn-default.focus,
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:hover,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #adadad;
}
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: -50px;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #2e6da4;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.btn-primary1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: -10px;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #2e6da4;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.form-control {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
.col-sm-2 {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.col-sm-10 {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.DemoBS2 {
  margin-top: 110px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
p {
  background: #444;
  color: #4ee255;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  border: 2px solid #fa4b2a;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #ccc;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png">
  <title>Create notes</title>
  <link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/style3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header" id="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" name="logo" id="logo">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation" id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="notes.html" class='active'><span>Notes</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="exam.html"><span>Exams</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="noteTitle">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Title:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="titleofnote" value="Note 1" placeholder="Click here to enter title.">
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="saveAndClose()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span> Save and close</a>
    </div>





    <div class="DemoBS2">
      <!-- Toogle Buttons -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle-example">Terms</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle-example">Enumerations</button>
      <div id="toggle-example" class="collapse in">
        <p>I don't know how to hide this. This should only show</b>
          when the button is clicked in terms(button)</b>Please help thanks.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/createscript.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: when its offline, I cannot use the jquery, What should I do?

Comment: @ZhacantalLizardo Why not use when offline?

Comment: you can download this jquery from jquery.org and then add into your page it work fine

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to hide in css as:

#toggle-example p{display:none;}

and in jquery on click on Terms button, you need to toggle as:

```
$('#toggle-example p').toggle();
```